# jQuery call function from click event and without event with parameters

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I have a situation where I want to call a function from document ready and on click.

```
var load_report = function(params) {
    report_name = params.data.report_name;
    // code continues
}
```

I can call it on click -

```
$("#report-" + report_name).click({'report_name': report_name}, load_report);
```

However, I also want to call if from `$(document).ready()` if certain constraints are met -

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (($.url().param()) && ($.url().param('report_name'))) {
            report_name = $.url().param('report_name');
            // Call load_report with report_name parameter
        }
    }
```

I have tried - `load_report({'report_name': report_name})`, `$.call({'report_name': report_name}, load_report)`, `$({'report_name': report_name}, load_report);` and none of them work.

`load_report({'report_name': report_name})` looked the simplest and most promising, but fails on `params.data.report_name` because `params.data` is undefined. Basically, all I need to do here is convert the dictionary into a format that can be interpreted the same way as it is with the `.click()` event data.

My question is - how do I call load_report function with my parameters without binding it to an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to remember the data key

```
load_report({data : {'report_name': report_name}});
```

or just trigger the event

```
$("#report-" + report_name).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

All you would have to do is `load_report({'report_name': this.id.replace('report-', '')});`.

```
$("#report-" + report_name).click(function(){
    load_report({'report_name': this.id.replace('report-', '')});
});
```